# Is there any mission in assassin's creed unity similar to the boat mission in assassin's creed 2?

Tags: assassins-creed-2, assassins-creed-unity

There was a mission in Assassin's creed 2 where you had to kill Savonarola's 9 lieutenants. One of them, the merchant, was stationed on a ship, and had many guards on the ship patrolling constantly. I was wondering if there's any mission in assassin's creed unity like that.

Comment: Why is this tagged with AC4? AC4 is Black Flag, not Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm gonna answer as honestly as I can.

In one way **NO** there is no mission like that because the game is set in the **French Revolution** in **Paris** so there were no boats/ships like that there. So in that sense there is no mission like that.

**BUT**

In the sense that there were many patrolling guards the game features a lot of missions that require really good skills in stealth and require you to blend and be a **blade in the crowd**.

Unity completetely increased the amount of guards patrolling in missions and many people consider the game harder because of that.

Comment: Thanks, before accepting your answer I'll wait to see if somebody else gives me a better one (though I don't think that will be the case).

Comment: No problem. I liked your answer. That was one of the best missions in AC 2 for me. AC Unity has many similar in the way of killing your target in a crowd and juggling the crowd like the AC 2 one. But nothing  so special as sneaking through the crowd than shooting the guy in the boat. God I miss Patrice Desilets

Comment: Well if you liked that mission too then check out my video on it :) http://youtu.be/o6Hcx8s9ROo